# several urls to the same page in Joomla

Tags: url, joomla, joomla-k2

I have a page (item in k2 terms) in joomla with alias "sprite creator", whitch has url: http://spritetools.com/index.php/software/item/3-sprite-creator

then I've changed alias name of corresponding item onto "animator" and my url became: 
http://spritetools.com/index.php/software/item/3-animator

the problem is that now both urls are exist! (the worstets thing is that the first one is indexed by google and the second one is not!)

How can I delete first url? I want to have only a unique link to this page.

Thanks for any assistance.

Joomla 2.5
k2 2.6

Comment: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=699954

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer is coming from http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=618&t=699954 is to set in the frontend the robots value to "no-index no-follow"

the list of all existing (NOT including possible copies) urls you can get from online sitemap builder http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/
But how to get old urls?

didn't check it yet...

any other suggestions?